# Disable insert key in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

I've been trying to find instructions to disable the insert key in Windows 10 but all the answers are for earlier versions. For example, they require changing "Keyboard layout" in regedit but that entry no longer exists. Can anybody please help? I keep accidentally toggling into "Overwrite mode" every time my fat fingers hit the insert key.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Win 10 I used to disable the Caps Lock key by a regedit. With Win 10 this was no longer possible (at least for me). However, there is a program called SharpKeys that works well - I disabled the Caps Lock easily. Haven't tried the Insert key however I believe you should be able to do so.I did check and the Insert key is listed under the groups "Special Keys" so it should work fine.

You can find SharpKeys here:

http://www.randyrants.com/

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? SharpKeys works well for me, remapping several keys, including CapsLock and Insert..

Comment: I guess that's because the link at the end of your answer sends to a website or blog homepage, not the page where the software you mention is available for download. Anyone searching for SharpKeys on their favorite search engine will find a plethora of website to download it from, though.

Comment: For anyone reading this years later, the above comment is inaccurate -- While it may look like a blog, the website that @Dugly linked to is actually the homepage for the author of ShartKeys (randyrants), as noted because the Github repo is https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my windows 10 laptop and here's how I fixed it:
SHIFT + INSERT
This should disable (or enable) the Insert funcion. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your laptop has a specialized keyboard that uses this key combination to enact this change. OPs question doesn't indicate which form factor of computer they have.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible via Microsoft's Power Toys addon for Windows 10. Install Power Toys, then configure the "Keyboard Manager" element:

1. Enable keyboard manager
2. Click "Remap a key"
3. Add a physical key (plus sign) and choose "insert"
4. Map it to "disabled" (first item in the list)